How can I select distinct three columns then select full table based on that set in Typeorm
I have this typeorm model:

@Entity({name: "role_permissions"})
export class RolePermissions {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    @JoinColumn({name: "role_id"})
    role_id: number

    @ManyToOne((type: any) => Role, (role: Role) => role.id)
    @JoinColumn({name: "role_id"})
    role: Role;

    @PrimaryColumn()
    permission_id: number

    @OneToOne(() => Permission)
    @JoinColumn({name: "permission_id"})
    permission: Permission

    @PrimaryColumn()
    @JoinColumn({name: "organization_id"})
    organization_id: number

    @PrimaryColumn()
    @MaxLength(7, {message: "soato must be 7 characters maximum"})
    soato: string
}

Three columns role_id, organization_id and permission_id are references to other tables (Typeorm models).
This is a sample data that I have:



role_id
organization_id
soato
permission_id




9
1
17
1


9
1
17
7


11
1
1735
3


10
1
17
3


10
1
17
1


10
1
1726
4



In raw sql I would do something like this:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (role_id, organization_id, soato) 
  role_id, organization_id, soato, ARRAY_AGG(permission_id) AS permissions 
FROM role_permissions 
GROUP BY role_id, organization_id, soato

and get this:



role_id
organization_id
soato
permissions




9
1
17
[1,7]


10
1
17
[1,3]


10
1
1726
[4]


11
1
1735
[3]



In TypeOrm I want to select the above result with permissions populated. I tried both AppDataSource.manager.find() and AppDataSource.manager.createQueryBuilder() but could not come up with any useful solution. Below I provide Role, Organization and Permission models just in case:

// short version models
@Entity({name: "permissions"})
export class Permission {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @Column()
    description: string
}

@Entity({name: "roles"})
export class Role {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @OneToMany((type:any) => RolePermissions, (perm:RolePermissions) => perm.role)
    // @JoinColumn({name: "organization_id"})  // Foreign key
    permissions: RolePermissions[]
}

@Entity({name: "organizations"})
export class Organization {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    full_name: string

    @Column({default: true})
    status: boolean

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date
}


